# draw debug shapes with box2d in ios, how?

Tags: iphone, ios, box2d

Im using the latest cocos2d iphone 2.0 with box2d (dont know the version).

I try to display the shapes in debug mode, how do I do that?

Regards
Mirza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the two box2d samples that come with cocos2d. They are drawing the box2d shapes.

If that does not help, check out [this](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/setup-ios) tutorial and S.O. [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990475/cocos2d-box2d-how-to-debug-show-bodies).

Comment: the box2d samples are confusing, the http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/setup-ios is not cocos2d based so its hard to convert, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990475/cocos2d-box2d-how-to-debug-show-bodies I tried it without success, any other ideas

Comment: You should try searching on Google for box2d tutorials. You might find one that is easy enough.